# Excel VBA Copy and Pasting Variable Selection (changing worksheets) to a new Workbook and saving as CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I nearly have this done, except nothing is being pasted.  **MY PROBLEM:** The exporting and save functions seems to work as it creates a new workbook and saves, but it is empty.

I am having the user select which worksheet they want to extract a static range from (the variable is the worksheet).  Each sheet is named by the week number (52 separate worksheets) plus a couple of background data sheets, which offsets the worksheet visible name from what excel calls the worksheet by 4.  Meaning sheet1 is called "Labor", while sheet5 is called "1" - for the first week of the year.

Anyways, that variable is passed through the lstExportInvoiceWeek combobox by the user.  from that selection, I want to copy a static range (BA6:BT200) and then paste it into a csv file.

Here is my code.  **The pasting isn't working.**  **The new workbook is saving blank.**

```
Private Sub cmbInvoicesExport_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim CurrentFileName As String
CurrentFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Debug.Print "Active File: " + CurrentFileName


Dim wsexport As String
wsexport = cboExportInvoiceWeek.Value
Worksheets(wsexport).Activate
Worksheets(wsexport).Unprotect

Range("BA6:BT200").Copy

Workbooks.Add Template:="Workbook"

Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Dim file_name As Variant
file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv")

If file_name <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
    MsgBox "File Saved!"
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Workbooks(CurrentFileName).Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `ActiveSheet` Instead use `Workbooks("YourWorkbook.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate`

You need to reference the Workbook target to paste the data.

Comment: agreed when using multiple workbooks or worksheets for that matter assign them to variables and name them explicitly in the code.  In this way you always know what workbook-worksheet you are referring your actions to.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I am trying to understand specifically what I should edit.  In the code, I don't know the name of the new workbook yet when it pastes so how do I reference it without knowing this?